# Is it possible to add regions later in DynamoDB GlobalTable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

AWS recently came up with GlobalTable to enable multi-master, fault tolerance setup across different regions. One of the constraints seems to be that the "Table must be empty" to setup GlobalTable.

Question is - Can I start off with 2 regions in US and then expand to other regions as we grow? If yes, above mentioned constraint wouldn't be true.

Has anyone tried GlobalTable yet? any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick update: as of November 2019 this feature is now available
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/you-can-now-enhance-availability-of-your-existing-amazon-dynamodb-tables-by-adding-global-replicas/

The catch is that dynamodb tables now come in two versions and all tables created before 11/21/2019 (old version) do not have the feature enabled.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GlobalTables.html

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer based on the example you gave.

Let's say you have two DynamoDB tables, one in *us-east-1* and another in *us-west-1*. As per DynamoDB's terminology, these two tables are *replica tables*. Now, you want to add another table in, say, *eu-west-1*.

The answer is, you can, but only if the following constraints are met according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/globaltables_reqs_bestpractices.html?shortFooter=true) documentation:

> - The table must have the same partition key as all of the other replicas.
> - The table must have the same name as all of the other replicas.
> - The table must have DynamoDB Streams enabled, with the stream containing both the new and the old images of the item.
> - None of the replica tables in the global table can contain any data.

In other words, your tables in *us-east-1* and *us-west-1* must be empty. If they aren't, you won't be able to add the one in *eu-west-1* to the global table.

Comment: Thanks. my problem is the last bullet point "None of the replica tables in the global table can contain any data."

Comment: Yeah, that's a constraint that you'd have to work around.

Comment: that last point is a HUGE gotcha and severely limits use cases for global tables. how often do you know at the beginning of a project which regions you'll need globally? backfilling/copying ddb records is insanely complex -- especially once those tables grow.  another half-baked service from aws...